Two verb in that/relative clause
I saw this definition for "assertion" in the Cambridge dictionary:

a statement that you strongly believe is true.

and This confused me. In sense, it must mean "You believe that a statement is true." But It also, grammatically, can be " there is a statement which you believe, and that statement is true.
namely, which one is it?
a statement (that you strongly believe) is true or
a statement that (you strongly believe  is /to be/ true)
If you say it is quite understandable because of this context, other examples can be given:
The man that I told is ugly.
(You told me the man and you say now he is ugly or what you told was he's ugly then, and now you are pointing him?)
likewise: The house that I think is beautiful. and so on
footnote: If there are two verb like above examples, must not it be one belongs to relative/that clause and other the head noun which is modified by relative/that clause?
footnote: Consider this sentence: This situation that you think is right is wrong.

No dictionary definition makes an assertion. The sentence 'A statement that you strongly believe is true.' [ie 'A statement (that you strongly believe is true) is true.'] is infelicitous as a typical definition: the reading, to match the noun being defined, must be a NP: 'a statement that you strongly believe to be true'.


a statement (that you strongly believe) is true

is not a definition of a noun. It's a sentence that describes a state of affairs. Word definitions are not generally full sentences, they're phrases that can be substituted in place of the word being defined (although this may be approximate, since the replacement may not be idiomatic).
So the actual definition must be

a statement that (you strongly believe is /to be/ true)

because this describes a kind of statement.
You should also look at the example usage:

I certainly don't agree with his assertion that men are better drivers than women.

Your first interpretation wouldn't make sense in that sentence.

Okay but "you strongly believe is true" isn't awkward?

I don't think so.

or it can be sentence like: This situation that you think is right is wrong.

Believe here doesn't mean 'believe the statement', but 'believe that it is true'.

@MaşukHaspolat "Trump was elected President 2 weeks ago" is an assertion.
